# Parsing JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to using JSON. On subscribing to a webservice I receive a json response as given below.

```
1024760833990-36891Customercustomer realtime20110914 10:48:10NNNYYYYN{"hostName":"uat91w82m7","data":{"view":{"columnValues":[{"DisplaySymbol":"MSFT Jan 19 '13 $35 Call","Symbol":"MSFT--130119C00035000","Quantity":1.0,"Price":0.71,"ChangeValue":0.01,"ChangePercentage":1.41,"DaysGainValue":1.0,"PriceAdjusted":false}],"columnHeaderCodes":[1,2,3,4,11,5],"viewName":null,"quoteType":0,"accountNumber":"39903689","asOfDate":1316022555984,"totalMarketValue":"71.0","todaysGainValue":"1.0","annualGainValue":"0.0","pagination":{"nextPositionMarker":"","pageNumber":1,"posPerPage":500,"posDetailPerPage":50,"totalNumberofPositions":1,"markerLength":0},"viewType":3,"portfolioId":null,"customView":false,"displayNetWorth":1,"groupOptions":"G0","viewID":null,"widgetType":null,"columnHeaders":null,"totalPositionCount":0,"easternDaylight":true,"widget":false}},"smUser":"102476083","success":true,"sysdate":1316022555992,"message_info":null,"message_type":null}
```

I am trying to display certain parameters on my page. So how to I parse it.

ANSWER : just remove `1024760833990-36891Customercustomer realtime20110914 10:48:10NNNYYYYN` through PHP or any other server side script and them parse it to jQuery, i'm damn sure it will do the job.

Comment: See e.g. the examples on getJSON() in the jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: That's assuming you're using jQuery - if you're not, please post the library you're using (eg Prototype, Mootools, etc)

Comment: [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: I am using jQuery. I have gone through the link before. But I am not able to exactly figure what is the hierarchy of response.

Comment: Is the "1024760833990-36891Customercustomer realtime20110914 10:48:10NNNYYYYN" bit part of the response? How did you grab the response that you posted?

Comment: The snippet posted is not valid JSON.

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/ doesn't like the formatting of your JSON string.

Comment: @Ates: I figured out why the time is getting added to the JSON response. It was the cookie that I am using to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First paste your JSON into [JSONLint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) to make sure it's valid JSON. What you provided in your question is not valid.

Secondly you can parse it with JQuery using [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) or with old skool JS using [JSON.parse](http://www.json.org/js.html).

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have a correctly formatted JSON string, all you have to do is use JSON.parse(string).

```
var JSON_string='{"name":"Jason","age":22}';
var JSON_object=JSON.parse(JSON_string);
console.log(JSON_object.name+' is '+JSON_object.age);
```

Comment: You've created a scoping / naming conflict here.  You can't declare `JSON` and then attempt to use `JSON.parse`.  You need to store your variable in something more local like `myResponse` or `myJSON`.  Otherwise, you're just going to get an undefined error with this code snippet.